# Java javac compile with classpath

Tags: java, compilation, classpath

I was wondering if it's possible to include a jar in the classpath when compiling instead of executing. At the moment I am just checking to see if my PostgreSQL driver can be found

everything is in the same location for testing purposes so

```
program/
    DriverCheck.java
    DriverCheck.class
    postgresql-longassname.jar
```

DriverCheck.java contains

```
public class DriverCheck {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
            System.out.println(Driver Found);
        } catch(Exception log) {
            System.out.println(Driver Not Found);
        }

    }

}
```

If I compile and execute this as normal

```
# javac DriverCheck.java

# java -cp ".:./postgresql-longassname.jar" DriverCheck
```

It works as I get the output

```
Driver Found
```

However if I try to compile and execute in this manner

```
# javac -cp ".:./postgresql-longassname.jar" DriverCheck.java

# java DriverCheck
```

It does not work as I get the output

```
Driver Not Found
```

Why is this and is there a way for me to use the second method for including jars?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why is this and is there a way for me to use the second method for including jars?

It's because specifying the classpath for compilation just tells the compiler where to find types. The compiler doesn't *copy* those types into its output - so if you want the same resources available when you execute, you need to specify the classpath at execution time.

In this case the compiler doesn't need the extra jar file at all - nothing in your *source* code refers to it... but you *do* need it at execution time... which is why your original approach works and your second approach doesn't.

Comment: I appreciate the thorough explanation, I clearly misunderstood how javac handles jar files